# What is the best practise for php sleep function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

For example in php we could put in a loop a sleep function for 5 min where could pause the execution than loop back where we could get new fetch result from database or other instances how can this be done in javascript as the only way is to set timeout and call the same function inside it,
Thank you.

Comment: The question is this will not pause the loop as sleep() function does correct me if i am wrong

Comment: you can't pause JS, because it is single-threaded; this would potentially freeze your whole page. You can only outsorce a chunk of code into a function and tell JS: call this function in x ms, like "call me back": [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). And you can say JS: I need this function executed every 5 minutes (unless I tell you different) that is [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: The real question should be why you need that functionality at all? Apparently you're solving a problem and for some reason it seems that a `sleep()` would help you out (note: sleep in php is ultra bad because it wastes CPU cycles, it's inefficient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments above, javascript is single-threaded and so this is not possible unless you wrap the code you want to execute after the delay in it's own function.

You could however make some kind of progress storage system whereby you keep track of what stage you want different pieces of code to execute based on the pause cycle, for example:

```
var stage = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  executeStage(++stage); // Iterate stage
}, 300000); // 5 mins

var executeStage = function(stageToExecute) {

  // Put any code you want to execute at EVERY stage here
  console.log('this code will execute no matter what stage is set');

  // Now execute code specific to just this stage
  switch (stageToExecute) {
    case 1:
      // Put stage 1 code here
      console.log('Stage 1 executes here');
      break;

    case 2:
      // Put stage 2 code here
      console.log('Stage 2 executes here');
      break;

    // And so on
  }
}
```

The above is just an idea, it really depends on your use case which has not been explained very clearly in your question. You should also bear in mind that the first stage won't execute until 5 minutes have passed with `setInterval`, so if you want to execute a stage then wait 5 minutes, you'll need to add a call to `executeStage(++stage)` outside of the `setInterval` call.